# ajax reload page reload facebook button

Tags: ajax, facebook, jquery-mobile, twitter

I have searched stack and found some topics but none of them show a complete code snippet so im still in the dark after trying several snippets and partial code segments.

Could someone clarify how to have jquery mobile + twitter and facebook buttons re-appear when the page is reloaded with ajax?

It is really not clear or the twitter and facebook api's changed making it not working anymore.

I do this for Facebook

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
      try{
          FB.XFBML.parse();
      }catch(ex){}
  });

But no button reappears